# A utility to place text over image in application run-time

Tags: android

A **android application utility** that allows the user :

1. Add an image
2. Add some text
3. Put that text over image place it anywhere {drag} on the image in application run-time.

**I know about adding the image but I have no idea about how to place a text over image in run-time.**

I am an android beginner and don't know much about inbuilt packages.Hence, please guide me on the right path!

Comment: We aren't going to write your app for you.  Come back with some research done and a single specific question.

Comment: head me toward the right article, I could not able to find out one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with using `RelativeLayout`. You should make a `RelativeLayout` in your java code. Put you `Imageview` inside it. Then put you `Textview` inside it. Make them alight both of them to `Parent Left, Top, Right an Bottom`. Then you add this `RelativeLayout` to you desired place in the layout you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.